# TLSv1 support in embedded Jetty server

Tags: java, ssl, embedded-jetty

I am running embedded Jetty server with https/TLS enabled on it. It works perfectly with all modern browsers (TLSv1.2).
We have a legacy browser (.exe whose code cannot be changed/checked) which we are trying to connect to Jetty server over https, which is failing.
I debugged SSL on jetty side and came to know that this browser is connecting using  TLSv1, so I did the following:

```
sslContextFactory.setIncludeProtocols( "TLSv1");
```

After this, I started getting error "no cipher suits in common" on server side. To pass this (I know this is dangeropus, but still for now), I did:

```
sslContextFactory.setExcludeCipherSuites();
```

After doing this, I don't see any error on server side, but still legacy browser is unable to connect. (It can connect to other https site though as facebook, google).
Server side logs after above change:

```
WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
called closeOutbound()
closeOutboundInternal()
SEND TLSv1 ALERT: 
warning,
close_notify
WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32
```

Any idea what can be wrong here? I tried to do a lot of googling on it but cannot work it through. I also tried enabling SNI on server, but with no luck.
Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks

**edit1**:
If I compare Jetty SSL logs with working request, I see below difference. Working request is sending application data also as below:

```
WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 1285
```

In non-working request, I see below additional line (TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA is cipher suite name):

```
Cached server session: [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
```

Comment: What exact version of the Java VM are you using?  TLSv1 is disabled at the JVM level on many Java implementations nowadays.

Comment: I am using jdk 1.8.0_161.  Setting sslContextFactory.setIncludeProtocols( "TLSv1") would not enable it?

Comment: If you are talking about _Oracle OpenJDK_ 1.8.0_161 then that revision included the JCE Unlimited Strength Cipher Suites (practically the first OpenJDK update to do so correctly), and has disabled vulnerable cipher suites SHA/SHA1/MD5 and RSA, along with disabling SSL thru SSLv3 protocols.  Have you tried connecting to your configured Jetty server using openssl's s_client with strict tls1 protocol behavior?

Comment: I am using Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12), not openjdk. I also tried connecting using Java HttpsUrlConnection with SSLContext =TLSv1 and it worked out.

Comment: Take a close look at your "legacy browser", it's TLS/1.0 might be an early implementation with many quirks.   My personal test is using `openssl s_client -tls1`, if it works there, then you know you have a proper TLS/1.0 on the Jetty side.  You might wind up having to reverting your OS / JVM and Jetty to get support back for that legacy browser.  Btw, if you can, state the details of the "legacy browser" in your question.

Comment: Also note: `TLS_RSA_*` ciphers are known vulnerable, and `*_SHA` are also known vulnerable for different reasons.  Are you sure you want to make all clients that connect to your server vulnerable just to support this one "legacy browser"?

Comment: I tried your openssl command and it returned: CONNECTED(00000888) <prints certificate> No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1342 bytes and written 334 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated

Comment: SSL-Session:
Protocol  : TLSv1
Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: xxx
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: xxx
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1538403485
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)     I hope above output is fine.

Comment: After checking legacy browser more, I came to know that it does not support SNI i.e. it needs the server that is not supporting SNI. I tried setting Java sytsem property jsse.enableSNIExtension to false, but still it did not work.

Comment: SNI is enabled in Jetty if the keystore contains the SNI information.   You might need to rebuild your keystore without the SNI information.

Comment: how to know if keystore has SNI info. I have a cert in keystore which has CN and SAN defined

Comment: If the X509 certificate has a subject alternative names it will trigger the SNI behaviors in Jetty (even names starting with `*.`), using the SniX509ExtendedKeyManager.

Comment: I am using Jetty9.2 which I think does not has SNI (I cannot find SniX509ExtendedKeyManager also)

Comment: On debugging further, it seems to be an issue related to close_notify exchange. My server sends close_notify so does oracle.com also and both of these do not work on this browser. Google.com does not send close notify and works perfectly.  Seems this browser does not handle close notify properly

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with Jetty 9.4.*
https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/3773
https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2807
which blindly excludes TLS1.0 and TLS1.1.
The fix
is (a) to call `setExcludeCipherSuites()` after SslContextFactory is contructed as mentioned above,
or (b) just override `SslContextFactory.setExcludeCipherSuites(final String... cipherSuites)` to do nothing, as below:

```
final SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory()
    {
        @Override
        public void setExcludeCipherSuites(final String... cipherSuites)
        {
            // do nothing intentionally.
        }
    };
```